# canvasjs column chart - have 'x' value in json object and I don't know where it came from

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, canvasjs

I'm trying my hand out at using canvasjs.

I have the following test code:

```
 9 $con = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=postgres") or die ("Could not connect to server\n");
 10 $query ="SELECT id as label, SUM(charge) as y 
 11         FROM bill 
 12         WHERE id is not null and cust_id=1 and charge > 0.05 
 13         GROUP BY id 
 14         ORDER BY SUM(charge) DESC 
 15         LIMIT 2";
 16 $result = pg_query($con, $query) or die ("Cannot execute query: $query\n");
 17 if (!$result) {
 18         echo "An error occurred.\n";
 19         exit;
 20 }
 21 $users = pg_fetch_all($result);
 22 ?>
 23 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 24 <html>
 25 <head>
 26 <script src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
 27 <script src="assets/js/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
 28 <script type="text/javascript">
 29 
 30 window.onload = function () {
 31         var users = '<?php echo json_encode($users); ?>';
 32         users = JSON.parse(users);
 33 console.log(Object.keys(users).length);
 34 
 35 console.log(users);
 36         var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
 37                 title:{
 38                         text: "Who's killing the Bill?"              
 39                 },
 40                 data: [              
 41                 {
 42                         // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
 43                         type: "column",
 44                         dataPoints: users
 45                 }
 46                 ]
 47         });
 48         chart.render();
 49 }
```

As you can see, I'm only selecting two fields: label and y. 
But somehow, when I look at the console.log output, I see the following data: (one record shown only)

```
Object
  label:"204751"
   x:0
   y:"63.6404"
```

I don't know where the x value is coming from.  But I think that's why my chart doesn't appear.  Well, i do get the labels appearing along the x axis but no y axis, and no pretty bars.
:(

Where have i gone astray?

**EDIT 1**

I think I know what's going on but I don't know how to fix it.
This is a sample of my php data before I json_encode it:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => 204751 [y] => 63.6404 ) [1] => Array ( [label] => 133236 [y] => 57.0851 ) )
```

After I call json_encode, it looks like this: 
[{"label":"204751","y":"63.6404"},{"label":"133236","y":"57.0851"}]

But after I call JSON.parse, that's when it bakes in the x value... and it looks like it corresponds with the index of the main php array.

If I change JSON.parse to $.parseJSON() then the x value is not included, but the chart still doesn't display.

**EDIT 2**

The help troubleshoot, I've hardcoded the data in javasript.
I've made the data points look like the json data that I'm dealing with. 
The code is here:  http://pastebin.com/HBj5iArn
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT 3**

I think I need to:

- use JSON.parse
- convert all "y" values in the object to int somehow.

Comment: You don't need `JSON.parse` after using `json_encode`. You can simply do `var users = <?php echo json_encode($users); ?>;` Note that there are no single quotes(`'`) around the php tags.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by looping through the json object and explicitly casting all "y" values to float:

```
window.onload = function () {
        var users = '<?php echo json_encode($users); ?>';
        users = JSON.parse(users);

for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var obj = users[i];
    obj.y = parseFloat(obj.y);
}
console.log(users);

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                title:{
                        text: "Top 20"
                },
                axisX: {
                        title: "Users",
                },
                axisY: {
                        title: "Dollars",       
                },
                data: [              
                {
                        type: "column",
                        dataPoints: users

                }
                ]
        });
//      chart.options.data=users;
        chart.render();
}
```